# Fail to override JPA persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a persistence.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>util.Pazienti</class>
    <class>util.Trattamenti</class>
    <class>util.Pagamenti</class>
    <class>util.Configurazioni</class>
    <class>util.Modpagamenti</class>
    <class>ent.Modpagamenti</class>
    <class>ent.Configurazioni</class>
    <class>ent.Trattamenti</class>
    <class>ent.Pagamenti</class>
    <class>ent.Pazienti</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:/Users/Alice/Library/Application Support/AppName/DB.SQLite"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I'd like to change url path with replacing my username with the correct username (the one which is using the application).

I wrote an "Init" function which should override jdbc:url property

```
Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<>();
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:sqlite:"+DB_FILE_PATH);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AppPU", persistenceMap);  
emf.createEntityManager(persistenceMap);
```

where

```
DB_FILE_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Library" + File.separator + "Application Support" + File.separator + "AppName" + File.separator + DB.SQLite;
```

but it doesn't work raising (long story short): `/User/Dave folder not present`, e.g. to simulate an installation in a pc with a user name  different from mine I changed jdbc:url replacing "Dave" with (a random name) "Alice". 
So, `System.getProperty("user.home") = "/Users/Dave"` (which is the current user is running the application, but Hibernate is still looking for `"/Users/Alice"` ignoring override and raising:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: path to '/Users/Alice/Library/Application Support/AppName/DB.SQLite': '/Users/Alice' does not exist
Error Code: 0
Java Result: 255
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestion will be appreciate!

Comment: Where's the error thrown? Can you post a stacktrace and the version of Hibernate you're using?

Comment: You mean "Hibernate is still looking for ..." and not "JPA is still looking for ...". "JPA" does nothing itself ... its a series of interfaces.

Comment: @mabi: I edited the question adding the exception message.

Comment: @NeilStockton you're right, Java and its technologies is still not perfectly clear to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know why, but swapping the second and third lines makes this code works!
I wrongly supposed that the third line overwrite the `persistanceMap` entries with the entries and value in persistence.xml tagged as `property`, but in debug mode doesn't seem so!

Here is the corrected code:

```
Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<>();    
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AppPU", persistenceMap);  
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:sqlite:"+DB_FILE_PATH);
emf.createEntityManager(persistenceMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` the correct property name?

Comment: you're right: javax.persistence.jdbc.url is the correct property name, but still doesn't work. I've removed "javax.persistence." for testing and I forgot to replace when I posted the question... Sorry. I've edited the question.